# select2 plugin issue in fetching data from ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

I am using select2 plugin for dropdown and having some issue over there.

**Final Result needed :**

- When I click on the dropdown ajax should pass the request.(which will
  fetch all the data)
- next time when ever i search inside the plugin
  the data fetched from that responded data.

**Reason for this :**
 - This will prevent unnecessary ajax requests everytime it comes.

**What I have Done :**

```
minimumInputLength: 0,
multiple: multi,
ajax: {                
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'post',                             
    data: function( request, response ) {
        db_fields = $('.select2-dropdown-open').prev().attr('sel');
        selected_val = $('.select2-dropdown-open').prev().val();
        return {                                
            sel : db_fields,
            term    : ( request).split( /,\s*/ ).pop(),                                
            ex  : selected_val
        };
    },
    results: function(data, page) {                    
        return {
            results: data
        };
    }                
},
```

**issues I am facing :**

I tried

```
cache:true
```

also but it didn't work.
as i have set minimumInputLength: 0 (so that it can pass ajax and popup the options at a time on focusing on dropdown)

on clicking , deleting element, adding element every time it passes ajax requests.which annoys a lot.

Comment: `data: function( request, response ) {` should that not be complete? or success?

Comment: that thing is right and working. :)